# How to find - The people you contact the most

Tags: ios

Hello all I am developing a extension app which will fetch-

- The people you contact the most.
- Most frequently used apps.

Any body have idea, How can I get these things.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Your app runs in a sandbox, which means that it is very limited in how it can interact with the rest of the operating system. This is to prevent security vulnerabilities from apps snooping on a user's behavior. For more information on this, and to see what you can and can't do in the sandbox, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html.